# How to send keystroke to executable?

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

How can I enter a keystroke programmatically through a PowerShell script?

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Loading...'

Function EnterKey {
  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
  #Where I want to get "|" keystroke programmatically
  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{|}")
}

Function StartUp {
  Write-Host "Environment"

  $exe = ([IO.Path]::Combine("D:\7ZipApp\7ZipApp\7ZipApp\bin\Debug","7ZipApp.exe"))
  & $exe 3 # argument 3 = 'Run local Sync'
  EnterKey
  Read-Host -Prompt $exe.ToString()
}

StartUp
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to programmatically press "|" for the executable after I pass in arguments, so send a key stroke to the console exe.

Comment: Sending a keystroke to a console executable is hit-or-miss. It would be far more robust to construct a correct `7z.exe` command-line that doesn't prompt and run that instead.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart true, I was just trying to see if I could get this scenario to work.

Comment: I would abandon your approach. Too problematic.

Comment: I can see that you want to send a keystroke programmatically from your question. My question was *why* you want to do it, i.e. what underlying problem you want to solve by doing this.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The underlining problem is that the console app (don't pay attention to the name its not 7 zip) is looking for input based on console.readkey() after it finishes execution to close.

Comment: Is that hard-coded, or does the application have an option to make it terminate automatically (`-quiet` or something like that)? Does it perhaps read from STDIN, so you could do something like `echo 'x' | & $exe ...`?

Comment: The correct solution, then, is to get the author of `7zipapp.exe` to fix the program so it stops doing that or to add a command-line parameter that prevents this behavior.

Comment: Conclusion I am going to get the executable updated instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Loading...'

function StartUp {
    Write-Host 'Environment'

    $exe = Join-Path "D:\7ZipApp\7ZipApp\7ZipApp\bin\Debug" "7ZipApp.exe"
    #& $exe 3 # argument 3 = 'Run local Sync'
    start $exe -ArgumentList 3

    Write-Host 'Type {|} to continue'
    while ((Read-Host) -ne '{|}') {}

    Read-Host -Prompt $exe.ToString()
}

StartUp
```

Comment: Looks like this is actually opening another command window and its not sending the key stroke to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

I have to go with the crowd here (from the comments):

> I would abandon your approach. Too problematic.
>
> My question was why you want to do it
>
> The correct solution, then, is to get the author of 7zipapp.exe to fix the program so it stops doing that or to add a command-line parameter that prevents this behavior.

That said, if you want a total **hack**, and this program only takes ONE input, at the end presumably, then the below appears to work.  I would use *sparingly*, perhaps never use it, but rather get the program fixed, but in my testing, this worked.

PowerShell:

```
$exe = 'C:\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'
'\r\n' | & $exe
```

Annoying C# program:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("I will force you to hit Enter to exit.");
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```